# Building MacVim -- missing some available features

Tags: vim, macvim, build

When I compile MacVim from source, I use a bunch of flags for configure:

```
./configure --enable-features=huge ...(enable python,ruby,perl, and c interpreters)... --enable-gui=macvim
```

But when I run vim, it doesn't have this feature enabled `--remote-tab-silent`, which I've been able to use in the past.

It also doesn't recognize the keywords `undofile`, `undodir`, or `relativenumber`. All of these worked when I used macports to install. So obviously, there's some features missing from my build, but I have no idea where to look to set the right configure flags.

Additionally, the only reason I am building from scratch is that the Command-T plugin requires the ruby interpreter, which macports doesn't compile by default. So if you have any suggestions how to get around that more easily than building from scratch, that would work as well.

Any idea what I should do to research this? Solutions? I'm very lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be `--with-features=huge` and `--enable-rubyinterp` to get what you want. If `undofile`, `undodir`, and `relativenumber` are missing, make sure you're compiling version 7.3, since those were added in that version.

Under MacPorts, try `sudo port install macvim +huge +ruby`.